# In Redux-Observable does the mapped to action only get called when initial action completes

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

In the code below the SET_COLOUR_RANGE action updates a value in Redux and this value is the payload of FETCH_COLOURS. So I would like the FETCH_COLOURS action to be called after the value in Redux has been updated.

Using the mapTo operator does the FETCH_COLOURS action only get called after SET_COLOUR_RANGE completes or is it called immediately after regardless?

```
import { selectColoursRange } from 'app/selectors/colours';

export const setColourRangeEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(ofType('SET_COLOUR_RANGE'), mapTo({ type: 'FETCH_COLOURS' }));

export const fetchColoursEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType('FETCH_COLOURS')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      fromPromise(
        axios.post(`/colour`, selectColoursRange(store.getState()))
      )
        .map(response => ({
          type: 'FETCH_COLOURS_SUCCESS',
          data: response.data
        }))
        .catch(error =>
          Observable.of({
            type: 'FETCH_COLOURS_ERROR',
            error
          })
        )
    );
```

Comment: That's very confusing. Action itself is just an object that doesn't complete. `action$` doesn't complete either because it would mean that there'll be no more actions in this Redux store. So it's hard to tell what you want to do...

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I've edited the opening post. Is it any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reducer will always get the action before the epic gets it.

So SET_COLOUR_RANGE goes to the reducer (thus updating the state), then it goes to setColourRangeEpic and gets mapped to a FETCH_COLOURS action. This FETCH_COLOURS action goes to the reducer, then goes to the fetchColoursEpic. By the time you call selectColoursRange(store.getState()), the state has been updated.